# Longpress inside actionsheet options

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to use UILongPressGestureRecognizer inside the  buttons of an actionsheet?

Shall I do different things, inside the action sheet if I touch  or if I make long press?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

YES you can

```
UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" delegate:(id)self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" destructiveButtonTitle:@"option" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [action showInView:self.view];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longtaped = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(recog)];

    [action addGestureRecognizer:longtaped];
```

it will work just fine
cheers

Comment: doesnt work... i want each button of the actionsheet has the longpress gesture

Comment: Still not, if i longpress with that code still call the: "actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex" but not longpress function...

Comment: i run that code before posting here this will work try to implement with that same and do not implement the  "actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex" method in your project....

Answer (score 1):

Either create your custom view which behave like ActionSheet. Also try setting actionsheet delegate to nil in below mentioned code.

```
-(void)AddactionSheet{

    UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" delegate:(id)self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" destructiveButtonTitle:@"option" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [action showInView:self.view];


    for(UIView *v in [action subviews])
    {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] )
        {
            //((UIButton*)v).backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];   // change button color

            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longtaped = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(recog)];

            [((UIButton*)v) addGestureRecognizer:longtaped];

        }
    }

}

-(void)recog{
    NSLog(@"Longpressed");

}
```

this code will work for you
if you want to add diffrent buttons with diffrent longpress than you have to add that "n" numbres of gestures
cheers